# Using a watch inside a link is causing an infinite digest cycle.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a directive that associates a score with a color.

I've made an attempt already, and the Plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQXYJWVwFXFkArLbPhuX?p=preview). The directive itself is here:

```
.directive('scorebox', function () {
    function link ($scope, $elem, $attr) {
        var one = 1;
        $scope.$watch('[score,ptsPossible]', function (newValue) {
            pctScore = newValue[0] / newValue[1]
            if (pctScore <= 0.4) {
                rating = 'low';
            } else if (pctScore <= 0.6) {
                rating = 'med';
            } else if (pctScore <= 0.8) {
                rating = 'high';
            } else if (pctScore == 1) {
                rating = 'perfect';
            }

            $elem.removeClass();
            $elem.addClass('scorebox');
            $elem.addClass(rating);
            $elem.text(newValue[0] + "/" + newValue[1]);
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            score: "=",
            ptsPossible: "="
        },
        link:link 
    }
})
```

I've got a couple of problems.

1. First, it's pretty obvious to me that I'm *not* supposed to do a `$watch` inside a `link` function. I'm creating an infinite digest cycle, and that's not good. I'm still not sure why, though.
2. I'm not manipulating the DOM correctly. Even though I'm calling `$elem.removeClass()`, it's not working--the element retains any classes it had before.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As @miqid said, no need to $watch both score and ptsPossible, since you only want to react when score changes (at least in this situation you are presenting).
2. The problem here, is you are using **jqLite's** removeClass function instead of **jQuery's**. If jQuery is not included before Angular in the code, Angular will instead use jqLite functions, which is like a smaller, much simpler version of jQuery. It is also, slightly different. jQuery's **removeClass()**, will remove all classes is no parameter is passed. jqLite will not do the same, it will just remove those classes that you pass as parameter.

You never included jQuery at all, so that's what's happening. Here is the edited [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nwCmlOJi3dHU2HjEsnFP?p=preview). You can check jQuery is now included in the top, and everything works as expected. And also the $watch is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion to get things working:

1. There's no need to `$watch` both `score` and `ptsPossible` since the latter never changes after the value is loaded from its corresponding attribute value. You also have access to `scope` variables inside the `$watch` callback function.
2. That's unusual as I would've expected your `removeClass()` to work as well. You could instead try `removeAttr('class')` here in the meanwhile.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5HeTEYNLm3b8qYdBkNy?p=preview) with the suggested changes.

Comment: I agree, in my current state, there's no need to watch both variables. However, in my target application, the number of possible points can change--I just didn't do that in this plunker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$watchCollection`and not `$watch`. You are passing in an array to `$watch`  which is how `$watchCollection` expects.

Comment: while @mithun_daa is right about watching a collection, i think that what you need is deep watch ( e.g `$scope.$watch(fn,true)`). `$watchCollection` is watching the structure while deep watch watches the values.